# Why do I have accept error when using Boost library saying "I'm missing websocket handshake connection field is missing the upgrade token"

Tags: boost, websocket

I'm a newbie in using Boost library.

I'm currently trying to connect websocket to a webpage hosting locally but having the error.

It keeps complaining that the websocket connection field is missing the upgrade token, and I don't have a clue what this is about.

The following is the code related to creating and interfacing with a websocket.

```
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("fail");
}

// Echoes back all received WebSocket messages

    session::session(tcp::socket&& socket, queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET *> *pQ)
        : ws_(std::move(socket))
    {
        cycle_cnt = 0;
        phase_cnt = 0;
        pconnectionQ = pQ;  
        m_portion = 0;  
    }

    // Get on the correct executor
    void session::run()
    {
       cout << "TODO session for " << endl;     
        // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
        // on the I/O objects in this session. Although not strictly necessary
        // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
        // thread-safe by default.
        net::dispatch(ws_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_run,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void session::on_run()
    {
        cout << "ON_RUN_SESSION" << endl;
        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type& res)
            {
                res.set(http::field::server,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    " websocket-server-async");
            }));
        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_accept,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void session::on_accept(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        cout << "ON_ACCEPT SESSION" << endl;
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");

        // Read a message
        // do_read();
        // boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

        // const int size = 256;
        // unsigned char pu8rawbuf[size];

        // for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //     pu8rawbuf[i] = rand() % 256;;
        // }

        cout << "accept connection" << endl;
        //m_portion = 0;
        //m_count_objects = 0;
        //m_itr_doc = jsonDocumentData.MemberBegin();
        //m_itr_arr = m_itr_doc->value.Begin();
        //m_is_end_file = false;

        do_write();
    }

    void session::do_read()
    {
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(
            buffer_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void session::on_read(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This indicates that the session was closed
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed)
            return;

        if (ec)
            fail(ec, "read");

        // Echo the message
        ws_.text(ws_.got_text());

        // auto jv = parse_file("./input2.json");
        // pretty_print(std::cout, jv);
        std::string stringForSending = std::string("TEST");
                std::cout << "SENDED\n";
        ws_.async_write(
            net::buffer(stringForSending),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
```

The error is occurring at session::on_accept() function. And the error message is as the below:

```
TODO session for
ON_RUN_SESSION
DO_ACCEPT LISTENER
DO_ACCEPT LISTENER END
ON_ACCEPT SESSION
accept: The WebSocket handshake Connection field is missing the upgrade token
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  fail
```

I'm connecting the websocket to node.js server hosted locally, and the port number matches of course.

The following code snippet is from the websocket client side.

```
const connectToWebSocketServer = () => {
  const socket = new WebSocket(WEB_SOCKET_URL)

  socket.onopen = (event) => {
    console.warn('websocket connection established', event)
    if (WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_DURATION) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        socket.close()
        console.warn('websocket connection closed')
      }, WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_DURATION)
    }
  }
```

Can anyone figure out what my problem is and how I can fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you posting incomplete code? Last I spent enormous amounts of time to make it complete, only to now basically find out that you're probably copy/pasting from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp). If that's the case, why don't you include full, self-contained code? You have to /actively/ leave out the details, which seems like more work?

Comment: @sehe my bad. I haven't really asked much questions on Stack overflow yet and was confused of how much code snippets I need to put here. I'll do as you suggest from now on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once again completed your example - this time as

**[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edbe18b9193cebb3)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
using net::ip::tcp;
using beast::error_code;

static void fail(error_code ec, std::string_view msg) {
    std::cerr << msg << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("fail");
}

struct PQN_DATA_PACKET {
};

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session(tcp::socket&& socket) : _socket(std::move(socket)) {}

    void run()
    {
        std::cout << "TODO session for " << _socket.remote_endpoint()
                  << std::endl;
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket _socket;
};

using Queue = std::queue<PQN_DATA_PACKET*>;

struct listener : std::enable_shared_from_this<listener> {
    net::io_context& _ioc;
    tcp::acceptor    _acceptor{_ioc};
    Queue&           _connectionQ;

    listener(net::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint ep, Queue& connectionQ)
        : _ioc(ioc)
        , _acceptor(ioc, ep)
        , _connectionQ(connectionQ)
    {
    }

    // Start accepting incoming connections
    void run() { do_accept(); }

    void do_accept()
    {
        std::cout << "DO_ACCEPT LISTENER" << std::endl;
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        _acceptor.async_accept( //
            net::make_strand(_ioc),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&listener::on_accept,
                                      shared_from_this()));

        std::cout << "DO_ACCEPT LISTENER END" << std::endl;
    }

    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
    {
        std::cout << "ON_ACCEPT LISTENER" << std::endl;
        if (ec) {
            fail(ec, "accept");
        } else {
            // Create the session and run it
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket) /*, _connectionQ*/)
                ->run();
        }

        // Accept another connection
        do_accept();
    }
};

struct server {
    net::io_context           _ioc;
    Queue                     _connectionQ;

    void run(tcp::endpoint ep, unsigned nthreads = 1) {
        std::make_shared<listener>(_ioc, ep, _connectionQ) //
            ->run();

        // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
        std::vector<std::thread> v(nthreads);

        for (auto& th : v)
            th = std::thread([this] { _ioc.run(); });

        for (auto& th : v)
            if (th.joinable())
                th.join();
    }
};

int main() {
    static uint16_t constexpr SERVER_PORT_NUMBER = 9797;

    server srv;
    srv.run({{}, SERVER_PORT_NUMBER}, 1);
}
```

Then I made a sample client in node:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });

    function sendNumber() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            connection.sendUTF(number.toString());
            console.log("Sending: '" + number.toString() + "'");
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
        }
    }
    sendNumber();
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:9797/', '');
```

I can run them fine:

```
./sotest & npm install websocket && nodejs ./test.js
```

Prints

```
[1] 14461
DO_ACCEPT LISTENER
DO_ACCEPT LISTENER END

added 18 packages, and audited 19 packages in 699ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
ON_ACCEPT LISTENER
TODO session for 
DO_ACCEPT LISTENER
DO_ACCEPT LISTENER END
accept connection
WebSocket Client Connected
Sending: '7599795'
Received: '7599795'
Sending: '3553782'
Received: '3553782'
Sending: '13810406'
Received: '13810406'
Sending: '12580747'
Received: '12580747'
Sending: '3757113'
Received: '3757113'
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out once again. I've just realized that the real problem lies with the websocket port somehow. When I start the nodejs server first and try to connect to the websocket, it complains the socket is already occupied (winerror 10013). I don't get why I can't get the regular connection. Could you guess why? 

P.S) I've uploaded the nodejs side of my code as well.

Comment: Hmm why are you running two servers? It seems that since your C++ code _listens_ and _accepts_ new connections, it is already a classical server. That's why I made a _client_ to _connect_ to your C++ server in nodejs

Comment: You are right once again. Thanks for helping me out :)